# Application crashing when clicking on Highcharts data export menu

Tags: java, android, android-studio, highcharts

I am using Highcharts in my mobile application, and it just stops working (crashes) when I click the highcharts export menu button.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

**note:** I am using the *demo* version.

```
  Process: com.ppgcc.mychart, PID: 21923
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com.ppgcc.mychart.FileProvider
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:606)
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:579)
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:417)
        at com.highsoft.highcharts.Core.d.onDownloadStart(SourceFile:64)
        at ic.a(PG:548)
        at An.handleMessage(PG:25)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: Please add your code and the error that it throws

Answer (score 0):

You need to add something like this to your android manifest

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
</provider>
```

where xml/file_paths declares the accessible directories.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it didn't work. I added the following codes and kept giving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer to your issue is here:

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-android/blob/master/README.md#export-module-requirements

Let me know if creating the provider_paths file resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help, however, the suggested solution does not solve the problem.